# Magenot 1.9.x : The URL "http://magedk.local/" is not accessible

Tags: magento-1.9, error, url, installation

> I can't install magento 1 because I have error:
>
> "The URL "http://magedk.local/" is not accessible."
>
> "Unable to read response, or response is empty"

[image]

Magento installing on docker.

Comment: try to do with ip address..

Answer (score 0):

Something DNS Lookup was failing. Our server support changed something, I don't know what, but it appears to have fixed it.

This was not a Magento application issue, it was a server issue.

Better to contact your hosting provider to get out from this error.